# i want to know how to Create a data frame from exciting one by dropping the following rows: 2, 4, 5, 8, and 9

Tags: r, subset

i tried to use subset and tried to specify the rows but it gives me all the 11 rows i had in my data frame

```r
examQual <- subset(examDF, nrow = c(2,4,5,8,9), select = c("name","score", "attempts", "qualify"))
```

if you can help to fix and solve this
thank you

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The second argument (`subset=`) requires a logical expression, not an integer one.

Here are two ways to do what you want:

1. Without `subset`:

   ```r
   examDF[c(2,4,5,8,9), c("name","score","attempts","qualify")]
   ```
2. With `subset`, perhaps a little hackish:

   ```r
   subset(examDF, seq_len(nrow(examDF)) %in% c(2,4,5,8,9), select = c("name","score","attempts","qualify"))
   ```

Comment: Thank you, for helping it worked